# ¿Cómo instalar dos versiones de Python al mismo tiempo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-2.7, setuptools

La idea es usar dos versiones del mismo lenguaje. Por defecto la distribution instala **python 2.7 y 3.8** (supongo que componentes necesitan la version 2.7 y la 3.8 debe ser para uso general).

Si se baja la fuente y compila, ¿qué argumentos debo pasar al configure para que instale en otro directorio y se reconozcan como dos **pythonpath** separadas?

Probé a hacerlo sin argumentos, pero al ejecutar **python3.8** mandaban varios errores de librerías no encontradas y otros **mismatch**.

Esto bajo **suse tumbleweed**.

Comment: Mira pyenv, te permite instalar diferentes versiones de Python (como un rvm)

Comment: Puedes utilizar ambientes virtuales así tiene diferentes versiones de python cómo también diferentes paquetes si usas Windows utilizas anaconda y lo creas si utilizas linux utilizas virtualenv para tener ambientes virtuales

Comment: Mi voto se va también por [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) sin dudar, junto a [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) para crear entornos virtuales si es necesario. Pero pyenv te permite instalar y manejar las versiones que quieras de Python, incluso distintas versiones de la misma rama, de forma simple. Yo además creo alias para la terminal del tipo py3.8, py3.7, py2.7, etc para simplificar el acceso a cada intérprete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instalas pip
`zypper install python3-pip`
Después instala virtualenv
`sudo pip install virtualenv`
Solo queda crear el ambiente con un nombre
`virtualenv namevirtualenv`
Lo activa desde la consola 
`Workon namevirtualenv o activate namevirtualenv`

Comment: Ahora bien, como manejo PYTHONPATH con virtualenv? no es necesario ajustarlo? Si instalo un programa que usa python3.x , tengo que instalarlo dentro del perfil virtual?